# Android back navigation for RadioButton

Tags: android, navigation, lifecycle

I have an actionBar than navigates between two list fragments called them 'All' and 'Favorites'. On the actionBar layout they are RadioButtons. 'All' is a list of data entries, and 'Favorites' is a filtered subset of that list. When in 'Favorites' I'd like the device's back button to always go to 'All'. How can I do this? Here is some of the relevant code, if it helps:

```
public class InstanceListActivity extends MyBaseActivity {

    private InstanceListFragment _listFragment;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        // Create content from resource
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_instance_list);

        // Get ListFragment
        _listFragment = (InstanceListFragment) getSupportFragmentManager()
                .findFragmentById(R.id.instance_list_fragment);

        // Add Filter menu
        ActionBar actionBar = getActionBar();
        if (actionBar != null) {
            actionBar.setDisplayShowCustomEnabled(true);
            actionBar.setCustomView(R.layout.actionbar_filter);
            final RadioGroup favorites = (RadioGroup) actionBar.getCustomView()
                    .findViewById(R.id.filter);
            if (favorites != null) {
                favorites.setOnCheckedChangeListener(new RadioGroup.OnCheckedChangeListener() {
                    @Override
                    public void onCheckedChanged(RadioGroup group, int checkedId) {
                        if (checkedId == R.id.filter_favorites) {
                            _listFragment.filterFavorites();
                        } else {
                            _listFragment.clearFilter();
                        }
                    }
                });
            }
        }
        // Handle search queries
        if (getIntent() != null) {
            handleIntent(getIntent());
        }
    }
...
}
```

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If I have understood your question correctly, override onBackPressed() method of activity and handle something like this.

In favorites.setOnCheckedChangeListener, save a **boolean variable globally**, in that activity. For example,

```
@Override
public void onCheckedChanged(RadioGroup group, int checkedId) {
if (checkedId == R.id.filter_favorites) {
isFav=true;
_listFragment.filterFavorites();

} else {
isFav=false;
_listFragment.clearFilter();
}
}
```

And override onBackPressed() method as follows.

```
@Override
public void onBackPressed() {
if(isFav){
    _listFragment.clearFilter();
}else{
    super.onBackPressed();
}
}
```

Hope this helps.